# Posting a meta question which asks for the reason for voting to close a specific question is not allowed?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548433/conditions-for-a-real-binary-quadratic-form-to-be-positive-definite) has 4 votes to close.
I have no idea why it was voted to close so heavily.
I need to know the reason because otherwise I cannot improve the question to avoid closure.
So I posted a meta question which asks for the reason for voting to close it.
It seemed to be deleted immediately.
Posting a meta question which asks for the reason for voting to close a specific question is not allowed here?

**Nov 5, 2013**
Since there seem to be some misunderstandings, I will state my case more clearly.
I read all of the members' opinions in [this meta thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11516/how-to-ask-a-question-when-the-asker-thinks-he-she-knows-the-answer). 
I edited [the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548433/conditions-for-a-real-binary-quadratic-form-to-be-positive-definite) to comply with them as follows.

- I added a statement that says I already had a solution of the problem.
- I added the motivation
- I put my solution in a spoiler box.
- I added the alternative-proof tag.

However, it still has 4 close votes. I have no idea why.
That's why I posted the meta question which a moderator deleted.

**Nov 6, 2013**
I would like to point out the following policy of StackExchange because it doesn't seem to be well-known and it is relevant to the present case.

> It’s also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, as long as you pretend you’re on Jeopardy! — phrase it in the form of a question.
>   So …
>       if you have a question that you already know the answer to
>       if you’d like to document it in public so others (including yourself) can find it later
>       it is OK to ask, and answer, your own question on a relevant Stack Exchange site.
>   To be crystal clear, it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

[Also related to this discussion:](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11516/how-to-ask-a-question-when-the-asker-thinks-he-she-knows-the-answer)

Comment: No, 9 people voted to close it. It was just reopened in between. And I deleted the meta question, because of the sheer amount of such meta questions you have asked, without there being much of an indication that you learn anything from the responses.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I edited the question complying with other members' opinions.

Comment: Why did you delete your previous comment just to repost it?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Just a grammar correction changing "to" to "with".

Comment: In your [last meta thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11516/how-to-ask-a-question-when-the-asker-thinks-he-she-knows-the-answer), you got plenty of feedback explaining why the community was objecting.

Comment: @T.Bongers As I said I edited the question complying with the community's members' opinions including yours in that meta thread.

Comment: @MakotoKato But you're asking why there are close votes and objection from the community. This was clearly explained in the previous thread - you seem to frequently open these threads and simply ignore the answers people give.

Comment: @T.Bongers I did not ignore them. I edited the question so as to comply with others. Still it has 4 close votes. I have no idea why.
That's why I'm asking for the reason.

Comment: If we go off-topic and back to the question on the main site, I have to admit that I would have started two meta threads asking why nine people had voted to close it! Perhaps it should have been closed the first time, but the extra four votes I disagree with - the post shows effort! Further, high-rep users are less likely to be simply asking for the solution to their homework, and so should be given more slack when asking questions with less motivation. (And I think that this question is borderline anyway - lots of much, much worse questions don't get closed.)

Answer (score 4):

I deleted the OPs previous meta-question asking for why there were closure votes. As T.Bongers has pointed out in a [comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11554/posting-a-meta-question-which-asks-for-the-reason-for-voting-to-close-a-specific#comment43746_11554), this has already been discussed in a [previous thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11516/how-to-ask-a-question-when-the-asker-thinks-he-she-knows-the-answer#question).

I could have closed your new meta-question as a duplicate, but I have doubts anyone would ever search for why exactly this question received this many votes to close, so I saw no purpose in not deleting it straight away and reducing the level of noise on meta.

Comment: I read all of the members' opinions in the meta thread you are talking about.
I complied with them.
I edited the question in the main site.
I added a statement that says I already had a solution of the problem.
I also added the motivation and wrote the solution I came up with.
I added the alternative-proof tag.
However, it still has 4 close votes.
I have no idea why.
That's why I posted the meta question which you deleted.